# How can I disable or remove a ceiling fan wall switch?

Tags: electrical, lighting

My ceiling fan is controlled by a remote, however the wall switch has to be turned on.  How can I remove this wall switch and have the fan hot all the time.

The switch has two set of wires going to it. One for the fan toggle (off and on) and one for the light toggle (off and on).

If I remove the switch and connect these two sets of wires together will that do the trick.. keep the fan hot all the time and not have to worry weather the wall switch has been turned off or on.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Assuming this isn't a 3-way or 4-way switch, all the switch does is connect all the stuff wired into it (excluding the ground conductor, of course). If you want it on all the time, just take the stuff that was attached to the switch and bond it together with wire nuts. Remove the switch and replace the switch plate with a blank wallplate.

For a no-wiring-required solution, you can also buy a switch lock like this: [image: switch lock]

That is held in place by the screw that holds your cover plate, and just mechanically prevents the switch from being moved. If you think the switch might be useful in the future, this is a little easier to reverse.

Comment: Yeah, I'd use the switch lock device shown. Converting to a blank plate doesn't improve aesthetics enough to warrant the effort, and the lock is easily reversible.